# Dialogflow date-range values incorrect

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow V2 (beta) api.

Windows 10.

My intent uses the system date-period entity for this week and next week in the training phrases. When checking the values of startDate and endDate I find they are incorrect.

The dates for next week are for Monday this week to Sunday next week and the dates for this week are for Monday last week to today (Sunday)

They start on a Monday and finish on a Sunday. I checked the Date and Time settings in Windows and changed the first day of the week from Monday to Sunday and ran the same training phrase over 6 times and still got the same start and end dates. I have attached the screen shots for both and you can see that the day on the taskbar is Sunday. I would expect the startDate to be a Sunday irrespective of what the first day of the week was set to, otherwise the intent action would return the incorrect response giving a different user experience.

[image: This week]

[image: Next week]

[image: date entities]